# Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a real sequence in $[0,1]$. Is there a partition of $\mathbb N$ indexed by the limit points of $(x_n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, set-partition

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of reals in $[0,1]$ indexed on the positive integers.

Let $L\subset [0,1]$ be the limit points of $(x_n)$, in the sense that $l\in L$ if and only if there exists an infinite subsequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $l$.

Can we always construct a partition $(N_l)_{l\in L}$, indexed in the limit points $L$, such that for any $l\in L$, the subsequence
$$(x_n)_{n\in N_l} \to l.$$

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by$(N_l)_{l\in L}$,  "indexed in the limit points"? In particular, I don't understand the $(x_n)_{n \in N_l }$ . Is $n\in N_l$ an integer?

Comment: For each limit point $l$, construct a countable subset $N_l\subset\mathbb N$. The sets $N_l$ must form a partition: $N_l\cap N_k = \emptyset$ and $\cup_{l\in L} N_l = \mathbb N$. Each set $N_l$ defines a subsequence $(x_n)_{n\in N_l}$. This subsequence must converge to $l$. Does this clarify?

Comment: Unfortunately, It makes it even worse. 1/ (addressed) What is $L_k$, the newly introduced notation?  2/ How are you constructing the countably subset $N_l$? why must they be a partition? 3/ What happens if $L = [0,1]$, and so we can't countably count the limit points?  4/ Can you give a specific example, say with $x_n = 1/2^n$?

Comment: For the sequence that attains all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ we have $L=[0,1]$. In this case we would need uncountably many sets $N_l$...

Comment: Sorry notation issue $L_k$ should have been $N_l$. The question asks if constructing such partition $N_l$ is possible. For $x_n=1/2^n$, the only limit point is 0, so $L=\{0\}$ and $N_0=\mathbb N$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: So essentially you are asking "Are the limit points countable?"

Comment: @sranthrop Shouldn't your comment be an answer? Or maybe such a no-effort question doesn't deserve one, according to the  [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards?

Comment: Thanks @sranthrop. That settles it then :)

Comment: Maybe I was too humble to put this as an answer, but Robert was faster anyway ;)

Comment: Wait: Would allowing $N_l=\emptyset$ change the answer? We can just focus on countably many $l\in L$, and ask for a partition only on those.

Comment: If you just want to partition a bounded sequence into subsequences that converge, I think that's always possible. This follows from Bolzano-Weierstrass (with a little care required in the argument).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen yes, partitioning into subsequences that converge would be useful to save the day given the negative answer to the question. Any reference that proves this explicitly? Extracting the $k$-th monotone sequence $N_k$ from $\mathbb N \setminus (N_1\cup ...\cup N_{k-1})$ seems to do the job

Comment: Yes, that's the rough idea - you have to make sure you end up with a partition, though, so for example you could always make sure that the smallest index you haven't used yet goes in $N_k$. You also need to deal with what happens if you have a finite set left over at some point. See Robert's edit below for a better result with a more detailed argument. (Be careful that his argument doesn't work out of the box for sequences with a finite set of limit points - there is an easier argument for that case anyway, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can have a sequence with uncountably many limit points, in fact every point of $[0,1]$ could be a limit point.  For example, this is the case with the sequence $0/1, 1/1, 0/2, 1/2, 2/2, 0/3, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, \ldots$.  You can't have uncountably many disjoint nonempty subsets of a countable set.

[EDIT]
If you choose a set $S = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots\}$ of limit points that is countably infinite, then yes: it is possible to partition $\mathbb N$ into disjoint subsequences $\mathbb N_i$, with $x_n$ for $n \in N_i$ converging to $s_i$.

You can construct the partition inductively.  Suppose we have $\mathbb N_1, \ldots, \mathbb N_k$, the corresponding sequences $\langle x_n : n \in N_i\rangle$ converging to $s_i$.  There is $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$|s_{k+1} - s_i| > 2 \epsilon$ for $i \le k$.  For each $i \le k$, there are at most finitely many $x_n$ with $n \in \mathbb N_i$ and $|x_n - s_{k+1}| < \epsilon$.  Thus there is $\delta > 0$ such that
for every $n \in \mathbb N_i, i \le k$, either $x_n = s_{k+1}$ or $|x_n - s_{k+1}| > \delta$, and only finitely many such $n$ with $x_n = s_{k+1}$: take $m$ be greater than the maximum of that finite set of $n$.
Let $\mathbb N_{k+1}$ contain $k+1$ if that is not already in one of the $\mathbb N_{i}$, and then an increasing sequence $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$ such that $n_1 > m$ and $|x_{n_i} - s_{k+1}| < 2^{-i} \delta$.  Since  $s_{k+1}$ is a limit point of your sequence, it is possible to choose this. By construction it is disjoint from $\mathbb N_i$ for $i \le k$, and every member of $\mathbb N$ is in some $\mathbb N_i$.

Comment: Does allowing $N_l=\emptyset$ for arbitrarily many $l\in L$, and requiring $(x_n)_{n\in N_l}$ converging to $l$ only for the countably remaining $l\in L$, bypass this and change No to Yes?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Much appreciated